# Visual Studio 2015 Resource View and Recource Compiler using different approaches to find icon files in project directory. How to fix it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

I develop MFC C++ project.

The Resource View (View -> Resource View) add icon files ("Add Resource" in .rc file context menu) relative to .rc file location, but Resource Compiler (rc.exe) trying to compile .rc file relative to project directory.

My .rc file is located in subdirectory inside project directory and I can't move it to the project directory by historical reasons and a lot of code. Is it way to force rc.exe find icon files relative specified directory or make Resource View use paths relative project directory?

I can't use absolute path because of many developers works on this project and it has been mapped to different directories on their hdd.

Sample directory structure:

```
Main->
    Res->
        Icons->
            icon1.ico
        app.rc
```

app.rc:

```
IDI_ICON1 ICON "Icons\\icon1.ico"
```

But during compile rc.exe shows error:

```
error RC2135: file not found: Icons\icon1.ico
```

When I fix it:

```
IDI_ICON1 ICON "Res\\Icons\\icon1.ico"
```

then rc.exe successfully compiled it, but Resource View can't open app.rc for edit (add icons, edit dialogs and so on) with error:

```
error RC2135: file not found: Res\\Icons\\icon1.ico
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Leave the file where the editor can find it and add an include path to the rc command (right-click the rc file in project window) for the resource file see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-rc-the-rc-command-line-

Comment: According msdn it should work, but it doesn't. rc.exe can't find icon files even when I leave only filename filename in .rc file IDI_ICON1 ICON "icon1.ico" and set absolute path in "Resources -> Additional Include Directory" option.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found that app.rc was excluded from build but it was included using #include in main .rc file that located in root project directory (Main). So when rc.exe trying to compile main .rc file it can't understand that icons are located in subdirectory relative to incuded app.rc. After I fixed it (removed "#include "app.rc"" from main .rc file, return app.rc it to build process) - project was built just fine (didn't need to add additional path to icons).